# Print last N characters from all lines in a file using cut

Tags: shell-script, shell, cut

I have following content in a file

```
foobar bar
bar foo foo
bar bar foobar
```

I would like to get get the last character from all the lines, also last 3 characters.

I am using following for loop workaround to get the desired output, but I guess `cut` command can do a lot better than this. Is there a way to do the same via cut?

```
$ cat test.sh
FILE=$1
echo "Last chars:"
for i in $(cat $FILE)
do
  echo ${i: -1}
# OR echo $i |tail -c 2
done

echo
echo "Last 3 chars:"
for i in $(cat $FILE)
do
  echo ${i: -3}
# OR echo $i |tail -c 4
done


$ sh test.sh
Last chars:
r
r
r
o
o
r
r
r

Last 3 chars:
bar
bar
bar
foo
foo
bar
bar
bar
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`cut` by itself doesn't have the concept of "the last N characters" on a line. However if you combine this with the `rev` program you can reverse each line, select the **first** N characters, and then reverse the result to get things back to the original order.

```
 rev | cut -c 1-3 | rev
```

Comment: I see that cut has the support to get first N characters (E.g. $ cut -c -3), I was under impression that cut also might have some expression to get the last N characters. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 6):

If on a GNU system, you probably want to avoid `cut` which only works correctly with single-byte characters.

You could use `sed` instead:

```
sed -n '/^.*\(...\)$/\1/p' < file
```

(skips the lines that have fewer than 3 characters and possibly non-text lines with some implementations).

Or to include the lines that contain fewer than 3 characters, printing only what there is:

```
sed -n 's/.\{0,3\}$/\
&/; s/^.*\n//p' < file
```

Comment: Why the redirection `< file` ?